# Pandas: How to read specific rows from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file `example.csv` like-

```
    name  |  hits
   ---------------
     A    |  34
     B    |  30
     C    |  25
     D    |  20
```

Using `pandas` in Python, how do I only read the rows with **`hits > 20`**? Looking for something like-

`my_df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', where col('hits') > 20)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the entire csv and do filtering like below

```
my_df =  pd.read_csv("example.csv")
my_df = my_df[my_df['hits']>20]
```

If you are having memory issues while reading, you can set `chunksize` parameter to read it in chunks

Comment: So you're saying that we always need to read the entire CSV file?

Comment: Yes. You can not filter the df based on the column value  while reading it using `read_csv`

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire csv and then use query() method to select the required section :

```
required_df = my_df.query("hits > 20")
```

or,

```
required_df =df.loc[df['hits']>20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a dataframe from any source, you can simply use

> dataframe_name['column_name'] (conditions) (value)

something like

```
dataframe['score'] > 200
```